# Flutter and Firebase - SteamBuilder unable to keep user logged-in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication and I'm trying to keep the user logged in for sometime. I tried using SteamBuilder but every time I relaunch the app it keeps redirecting me to login page. The authentication works perfectly, but I need to keep the user logged in instead of logging in every time I open the app. This is my main code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
          child,
        maxWidth: 1200,
        minWidth: 420,
        defaultScale: true,
        breakpoints: [
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(400, name: MOBILE),
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1000, name: DESKTOP),
        ],
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'myProject',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
                       useMaterial3: true,
       visualDensity: VisualDensity.comfortable,),
      home: StreamBuilder <User?> (
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
        initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          } /// else no internet connection??
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return HomePage(); //after-login screen
          } else {
            return Firelog(); ///login screen
          }
        }))
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I implemented Firebase Authentication:

```
  Future<String?> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return 'Success';
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'Email-Mismatch';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Password-Mismatch'; 
      } else {
        return 'Failed'; ///Other issues?
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error'; ///Firebase Server Problem?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` package. Then, make `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`.

Create method and variable as per below.

```
var userId;
getSharedPReferences() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  userId = sharedPreferences.getString('userid');
}
```

call that method in inistate

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
    getSharedPReferences();
    super.initState();
  }
```

return below code

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return userId != null
            ? HomePage()
            : const Firelog();
      }));
```

**Updated answer: if this page is only for check whether user is logged-in or new**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var userId;
  getSharedPReferences() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    userId = sharedPreferences.getString('userid');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getSharedPReferences();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return userId != null
            ? HomePage()
            : Firelog();
      }));
    });

    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should I return this code (Navigator.pushReplacement...etc ?

Comment: You can check above updated answer, if you don't need this screen. If your this page is only for check whether user is new or old so, you can just put updated answer code

Comment: I need example how to keep user logged in using firebase authentication. Your answer is not complete because doesn't include any firebase method.

Comment: Have you tried it? `SharedPreferences` works with `Firebase`. It also gives you the same user logged in who registered account.